# Limit public profile information

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, network-profile, privacy

Is it possible to restrict profile information about a specific Stack Exchange site ? For example, I'm using StackExchange for SO, Software QA, Personal Productivity, Area 51, but I would like to only show my accounts on SO and QA, hiding others profiles. 
A kind of separation between professional and "personal" stuff.
Thanks

Comment: I think this would be useful, especially considering the tie into Careers 2.0 ,as I would be happy to share my StackOverflow information with employers but I would prefer not to display my participation in [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) or [Islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com/) to avoid bias.

Comment: You could always create a second account for that. It's not forbidden, per se.

Comment: @slhck but if you *didn't* and only encounter the problem later, you're stuck.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely going to be closed, but I want to get a short bit of advice in before it is ..

***We're designed around the concept of one account associated with many sites, at the moment.***

What this means is, should you elect to maintain multiple *accounts* (not multiple profiles on sites using a single login, but multiple logins that are never associated with one another) .. you must be *very* careful to not mix them. If you accidentally associate one with another there's a *very* good chance that the system will merge them, and undoing that is an *extremely* difficult task that we can't always meet.

I strongly recommend using incognito / private browsing / separate browsers entirely if you want to go this route.

Just a note, in the hopes that you avoid an unfortunate surprise should you do this. Additionally, there's nothing wrong with having multiple accounts (aside from us not supporting it very well) *so long as you don't use them to do things you could not do with a single account*. This would mean not voting for your own posts, starring your own chat messages, coordinating flags between the accounts, etc.

Comment: Of course the having multiple accounts solution doesn't solve the: [use the account as usual, registering on many sites etc, *then* registering for careers, deciding you want to cut out all the personal stuff] problem. As far as I can see you would have to delete the personal half of your account

Comment: Maybe a feature allowing to just hide links on the profile would solve part of the problem. We would always be present with the same account everywhere, but would be harder to find all relations

Comment: @StéphanePiette We're considering that. I can't off the top of my head remember why that's going to be difficult, but it is an avenue we're exploring. Come to think of it, I need to find out where that is, if anywhere other than where it was the last time we talked about it.